# NetBeans ide save json file with charset utf-16le

Tags: json, netbeans, character-encoding, ide

I'm trying to save a file created in Netbeans with the charset utf-16le (to include chinese chars).
When i write inside the ide the chars i see them but when i save and reopen the file i see "?"for each chinese char.
[image]

there is a way to save in utf-16?
sorry for bad english, i'm italian (: